# What is the adverb you use when something increases drastically?

Tags: synonyms, adverbs

What is the adverb that is commonly used when describing something rapidly/drastically increasing? It's on the tip of my tongue and I can't get it out. It's not tenfold, rapidly, drastically, dramatically, stratospherically, etc. but similar. I think it has a connotation of quickly multiplying. (It's a single word.) It's driving me insane--any idea what it is?

Comment: Skyrocketing? ……

Comment: It's not an adverb, but when something increases rapidly it is often said to have "ballooned".

Comment: May be “exponentially.”. But exponentially has a specific meaning and is often badly misused as a synonym of the words you mention. Such a question is a matter of opinion, being a choice between many alternatives, so is not suitable for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Exponentially**

*in a way that becomes quicker and quicker as something that increases becomes larger*

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exponentially)

Comment: That is the word that I would go for, too, but be careful: 'exponential' can also indicate something getting relentlessly _smaller_, depending on the sign of the exponent in any given case. The _Guardian_ website has a very accessible article on this, from a few years back: https://www.theguardian.com/science/life-and-physics/2014/jul/20/the-meaning-of-exponential.